# Change hint programmaticaly with kotlin for material.textfield

Tags: android, kotlin

I am trying to change the text hint inside a `material.textfield` for example:

```
<com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
    android:id="@+id/textField"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textColorHint="@color/primaryDarkColor"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_marginRight="6dp"
    android:layout_weight="10"
    app:boxBackgroundColor="#A3A3A3">

    <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
        android:id="@+id/et_barcode"
        android:imeOptions="actionNext"
        android:digits="0123456789,."
        android:textSize="18dp"
        android:inputType="numberDecimal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:backgroundTint="@color/white"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>
```

I have a view model that has a live value:

```
private val _cardMm = MutableLiveData<String>()
val cardMm: LiveData<String>
    get() = cardMm
init {
    _cardMm.value = "ΤΕΜΑΧΙΑ"
}
```

Now I want to change it inside it view model and observe it from main fragment with following code:

```
    viewModelAddBarcode.cardMm.observe(viewLifecycleOwner, Observer {
        binding.textField.hint = it
    })
```

The error I get in Logcat is:

```
2020-12-04 17:45:12.937 14810-14810/com.example.myapplication.inventoryapp E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.myapplication.inventoryapp, PID: 14810
    java.lang.StackOverflowError: stack size 8MB
        at com.example.myapplication.inventoryapp.view.add_barcodes.ViewModelAddBarcode.getCardMm(ViewModelAddBarcode.kt:24)
        at com.example.myapplication.inventoryapp.view.add_barcodes.ViewModelAddBarcode.getCardMm(ViewModelAddBarcode.kt:24)
        at com.example.myapplication.inventoryapp.view.add_barcodes.ViewModelAddBarcode.getCardMm(ViewModelAddBarcode.kt:24)
        [...]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is probably here:

```
val cardMm: LiveData<String>
    get() = cardMm
```

You are assigning `cardMm` (itself) to getter, this causes looping until the stack overflows. I think you meant to assign `_cardMm`.

Comment: Υes exactly! I did not see that!! Thanks! It is a pitty after this question I got banned :/